# Closing and restarting DB connection during web2py request cycle

Tags: python, web2py

My db is SQL Server on a remote machine and I am encountering quite a bit of latency.
I have a method in a controller that is structured like this:

```
def submitData():
    parameters = db.site.select(...)
    results = some_http_post()  # posts data to remote server,
    if results:
        rec = db.status_table.insert(...)
        rec.status_tabl.update(...)
```

What tends to happen is that some_http_post() takes several seconds to get a response and I run out of threads 
When I hit web2py with more than 6 concurrent requests to submitData, I am encountering freezes in requests, rather than getting DB error.
This has the effect of stopping any further web2py requests.

I would ideally like to close the db connection before the call to some_http_post and start another db connection after it, but I don't see a simple way to do this with the DAL API. Is this possible or is there a better optimisation that I could be trying?

Answer (score 3):

Connection pooling is enabled by default.

If you add "pool_size=0" to the connection string this disables connection pooling and I assume the behavior to forcibly open/close each conn. instead of leaving them open.

If you need more threads (sounds like), increase your pool_size and see what happens.

OR, yes, you can use the DAL and do a db.close() and the connection is auto-reopened on first request

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling connection pooling: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06#Connection-pooling